# RAILS restful input security using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have restful input working with a RAILS app.

The following works fine:

```
http://my.url/types?type[typecode]=test&type[typedesc]=test%20description
```

But, if I add the gem Devise and put this into the Types controller, it won't work:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

How do I add the user, password to the rest input?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you __really__ want to pass the username and an unencrypted password in the url, you should look into the http basic auth ability of devise. nevertheless, i hope a GET request to that url doesn't create/change any data on your server ;)

Comment: Its a POST.  Should I look into OAUTH?